# Question on slice category

Tags: functors

Consider category $\mathcal{C}/Z$ consists of objects over Z, i.e arrows over $Z$. Let $h: H \rightarrow Z$ be a fixed object in $\mathcal{C}/Z$. Let $F=Hom(H,X)$. Show that under $F$, pullbacks over $Z$ are just products in the category of sets.

Comment: The usual notation for $\mathcal{C}_Z$ is $\mathcal{C}/Z$, and it is called the slice category. I assume $Mor_Z$ is intended to be the hom-functor of $C_Z$; you should use less ambiguous notation. In that vein, the objects are arrows, so it should be $Mor_{\mathcal{C}/Z}(h,-)$. Is the $X'$ an accident? Is it supposed to be just $X$? What categories does $F$ go between? (Obviously the codomain is $\mathbf{Set}$.)

Comment: @DerekElkins Thank you. I editted the question. I was intending $X'$ to be a different object but it doesn't seem to matter. Also, $Mor_Z$ denotes morphisms over $Z$ (I obtained this notation from Lang's Algebra).

Comment: What does an element of $Mor_Z(H,X)$ look like?

Comment: @DerekElkins $Mor_Z(H,X)$ are morphisms in the category of objects over $Z$. So an element of $Mor_Z(H,X)$ would be a commutative triangle $H \rightarrow X$ (where both $H, X$ have maps to $Z$) such that the composite $H \rightarrow X \rightarrow Z$ is equal to the map $H \rightarrow Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible direction to solve the exercise:

1. prove that fiber products of morphisms with common codomain $Z$ are products in the category $\mathcal C/Z$
2. (Enter the Yoneda) use the fact that representable copresheaves preserve limit to conclude the proof.

If you need additional hints feel free to ask.

**Addedum**(since the OP asked :) ): 
Your functor $F$ is nothing but the representable functor associated to the object $h \colon H \to Z$, hence by general results it preserves product: that is it sends product diagrams in $\mathcal C/Z$ into product diagrams in $\mathbf{Set}$.

By (1) products in $\mathcal C/Z$ are fiber products in $\mathcal C$, hence putting all together we get that $F$ sends the fiber products of $\mathcal C$ (i.e. the products of $\mathcal C/Z$) into products of $\mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try.

Comment: Isn't 1. is straightforward from definition of product and slice category ?

Comment: @S_j I guess that's depend on you. Everything can be trivial or incredibly complex depending on the person who's considering the problem.

Comment: I mean, saying that something is straightforward is not actually a proof, it's a trick to avoid giving details of a proof.

Comment: would you mind explain a bit further why would step 2 conclude the proof  ? (I am very new to category theory)

Comment: @S_j I made a little addendum, take a look and let me know if that helps.

Comment: thank you very much, Sir. I believe I got it now.